# Can we find the differences from 2 files like in TFS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to see the difference from two pages like in `.cs` / `.cshtml` files
Or anything in Microsoft technology.

**Example:** Compare server file with my development file of changes before deployment for my test.

Thanks in advance.

Tried by creating the batch file.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called a diff tool. There are lots of diff tools out there for comparing two text files. Feel free to research and pick one and use it. But Stack Overflow isn't a place to come to for tool reccomendations.

Comment: @mason - Thanks for the comment, I don't have a choice to use such tools. By the way found a solution by creating batch file.

Answer (score 1):

there is one built into Visual Studio. In fact, quite sure it is the default one that GitHub integreation used in Visual Studio uses.

So, from Visual studio,View->Other Windows->Command window.

this one:

[image]

Now, the command prompt DOES have nice intel-sense for folders and directories, but those path names are "messy". I been meaning to setup a helper utility to prompt/browse to the file dialog to select both files.

Regardless, the result looks like this:

command line:

[image]

And result:

[image]

Now, of course with github integrated right into visual studio?

I don't have to do anything more then choose this while looking at code:

right click in code, git->

this:

[image]

So, now that VS has 100% and VERY nice integration with GitHub?
(and I don't even know GitHub well, but in VS I don't have to).

So, I can at any time (since my last commits) simple right click in code and view the un-change (previous) committed code. You noted use of TFS, and quite sure it is the same.

Regardless, the "same" diff tool you probably been using now?
It is and can be used to compare any files - not just those limited that are part of a TFS or GIT repo.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. I was created a batch file to do this and it's working as expected.